# Instagram API Possible Solution

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have one question, with an Instagram Username. Can I get back data from that user? for example, get photos and number of followers? (only if profile is public)

I'm creating a website were users can upload their Instagram username @example and based on that scrap and create a profile on the website with their latest photos and the number of followers (all of this without logging).

I think This image will help to understand what I'm trying to achieve, Can someone guide me? this is possible with Instagram API?[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the instagram API documentation - https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was possible recently with `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1` but instagram recently blocked this possibility.
I'll update my post if I find a new method.

Comment: do you find out new method?